# Why I can't use nuget package from different folder?

Tags: c#, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I installed .net core nuget package in order to create application based on this framework. When I create a solution in visual studio community 2017 in default vs projects folder everything seems to be ok, but when I change destination folder (or create new solution in different folder) then program cannot start because of bug: `Assets file 'D:\c#\test\test\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.` Of course restoring doesn't help at all. Can you help me with this problem? 
Visual Studio version 15.5.2, windows 10.
Regards.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *change destination folder*? Of what? The NuGet dependency? The project? The solution? It would help if you would provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in particular showing how you are changing the directory and/or file structure (before and after).

Comment: I cannot provide such example because I don't know how to do this. This is my local problem. "Change destination folder" - cut and paste project or simply create new solution in different folder (in that case everything should register correctly at start but it doesn't)

Comment: Cut and paste a project in Solution Explorer, or in Windows Explorer? Are you nesting one project below another one? Again, it would help to provide an example. You can **edit** your question to provide additional details. Refer to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for code formatting instructions. You can use "code" to format text to look like directories [such as in this example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250543).

Comment: You can't use same project with a Nuget dependency from 2 different solutions. If it is crucial you can consider making this project a nuget package itself. Or another workaround could be to have both .sln files in the same folder.

Comment: I can at least confirm this _should_ work, all my solutions live at `c:\source\...` on my machine rather than the default user folder. When you create the new solution and project, have you re-added the NuGet package? You have to add the packages to each new project.